# Calculating days in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have an issue where, I'm trying to work out if a certain alert on a webpage is calculating sums correctly.  I'm using Capybara and Cucumber.

I have an alert that calculates records that expire within 30 days. When selecting this alert, the records are listed in a table and the date is presented in the following format, "1 feb 2016"

What I want to do is somehow take today's date, compare it to the date returned in the table and ensure that it's >= 30 days from the date in the alert.

I'm able to set today's date as the same format using Time.strftime etc.

When I try things like:

```
And(/^I can see record "([\d]*)" MOT is calculated due within 30 days$/) do |selection1|


  today = Time.now.strftime('%l %b %Y')
  thirty_days = (today + 30)
  first_30day_mot = first('#clickable-rows > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + selection1 + ') > td:nth-child(3)')

if today + first_30day_mot <= thirty_days
  puts 'alert correct'
else
  (error handler here)
  end
end
```

As you can see, this is quite a mess.

I keep getting the error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`

If anyone can think of a neater way to do this, please put me out of my misery.

Thanks

Comment: `first_30day_mot` is a string most likely.  May be `to_i` on it will help

Comment: I did try that and but the same error appeared.

Comment: That error appears whenever you try to add an integer to a string or any similar operation.  You can debug your code by inspecting values at the line number where the error is being reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least a couple of things wrong with your attempt.

1. You're converting dates to strings and then trying to compare lengths of time with strings.  You should be converting strings to dates and then comparing them
2. `#first` returns the element in the page not the contents of the element

It's not 100% clear from your code what you're trying to do, but from the test naming I think you just want to make sure the date in the 3rd td cell (which is in the 1 feb 2016 format) of a given row is less than 30 days from now.  If so the following should do what you want

```
mot_element = first("#clickable-rows > tbody > tr:nth-child(#{selection1}) > td:nth-child(3)")
date_of_mot = Date.parse(mot_element.text)

if (date_of_mot - Date.today) < 30
  puts 'alert correct'
else
  #error handler
end
```

Beyond that, I'm not sure why you're using #first with that selector since it seems like it should only ever match one element on the page, so you might want to swap that to #find instead, which would get you the benefits of Capybaras waiting behavior.  If you do actually need #first, you might consider passing the `minimum: 1` option to make sure it waits a bit for the matching element to appear on the page (if this is the first step after clicking a button to go to a new page for instance)

Comment: Thank you, this is doing what I need.  I'm fairly new to this so I was getting confused with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `selection1` to the string explicitly (or, better, use string interpolation):

```
first_30day_mot = first("#clickable-rows > tbody > tr:nth-child(#{selection1}) > td:nth-child(3)")
```

Also, I suspect that one line below it should be converted to integer to add it to `today`:

```
first_30day_mot.to_i <= 30
```

**UPD** OK, I finally got time to take a more thorough look at. You do not need all these voodoo magic with days calculus:

```
 # today = Time.now.strftime('%l %b %Y') # today will be a string " 3 Feb 2016"
 # thirty_days = (today + 30) this was causing an error

 # correct:

 # today = DateTime.now # correct, but not needed
 # plus_30_days = today + 30.days  # correct, but not needed
 first_30day_mot = first("#clickable-rows > tbody > tr:nth-child(#{selection1}) > td:nth-child(3)")

 if 30 > first_30day_mot.to_i
   ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not having much luck. Do you think, capturing the text in the xpath/css, then using Date.strptime to convert it to int would be better? Also changing the output of today as int

Comment: Please see an update, I took a second glance at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend not using Cucumber to do this sort of test. You'll find its:

1. Quite hard to set up
2. Has a high runtime cost
3. Doesn't give enough benefit to justify the setup/runtime costs

Instead consider writing a unit test of the thing that provides the date. Generally a good unit test can easily run 10 to 100 times faster than a scenario.

Whilst with a single scenario you won't experience that much pain, once you have alot of scenarios like this the pain will accumulate. Part of the art of using Cucumber is to get plenty of bang for each scenario you write.